# redux-form: throw SubmissionError after server validation error

Tags: validation, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I've been trying to use redux-form (v6.5.0) with submit validation and throwing a SubmissionError after server validation error on login.

In the example here [Submit Validation Example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/submitValidation/), the submit function uses a promise and throw a SubmissionError on a callback error, which works fine for me if I follow this workflow. But in my case I want to dispatch a login action on submit form and use a reducer to change the state in the store.

Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to do:

**LoginForm.js**

```
const LoginForm = ({handleSubmit, submitting, error,}) => {
  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" component={renderField} label="Email" validate={email}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Field name="password" component="input" type="password" component={renderField} label="Password" validate={required}/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Log In</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'loginForm'
})(LoginForm)
```

**LoginPage.js**

```
class LoginPage extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (values) => {
    this.props.dispatch(login(values));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.fetching && <p>LOGGING IN...</p>}
        <LoginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, `handleSubmit` only dispatches the login action and is not aware of the server error that will occur.

**Login action** looks like this:

```
function login({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: "LOGIN_USER_PENDING"})
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({type: "LOGIN_USER_REJECTED", payload: "Invalid username or password"})
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Reducer** looks like this:

```
case "LOGIN_USER_PENDING":
  return {...state, fetching: true}
case "LOGIN_USER_REJECTED":
  return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
```

I can successfully identify the error in the LoginPage but I cannot throw the SubmissionError outside of the handleSubmit function.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to throw this SubmissionError from another function in the component lifecycle?
2. If not, how to achieve that? Am I doing this wrong by dispatching the login action from submit, not using a promise from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check [`asyncValidation` example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/asyncValidation/). You need to add `asyncValidate` to your form configuration and you will be able to throw errors from your custom `asyncValidate` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes I had a look at asyncValidation, but it's not quite what I want to do since asyncValidate is to "run server-side validation while the form is being filled out." I don't need to run the validation before submitting the form here.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, but I don't use the SubmissionError mechanism that would do the job and display the error for me. So there still might be a cleaner solution.

Since I get the error in the LoginPage component when state changes, I just forward it to the LoginForm and display it manually.

**LoginPage.js**

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.fetching && <p>LOGGING IN...</p>}
        <LoginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} _error={this.props.error} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
const LoginForm = ({handleSubmit, submitting, _error,}) => {
  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {_error && <strong>{_error}</strong>}
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Log In</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

I'm happy to hear for any advice that would improve the solution anyway.